# "Priority only" notifications not turning off

Tags: cyanogenmod, notifications, bugs, oneplus-one

My OnePlus One with Cyanogen OS 13.1.2 has for some reason refused to shut off its "priority only" notification status, pressing on the notification icon in the dashboard doesn't do anything, nor does restarting the phone.

However, the phone doesn't seem to act like it's only priority only mode, but it's preventing me from switching to do not disturb mode or the actual priority only mode.

Does anyone have any idea how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an automatic rule (<kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Notifications</kbd> > <kbd>Do not disturb</kbd> > <kbd>Automatic rules</kbd>), regardless of the name or type. "Priority only" mode should stop and you should be able to regain control over the "Do not disturb" tile in the notification bar.